# Update Active Directory account information from asp.net and SQL server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I need to develop a update function (asp.net web application) that regularly update active directory (AD) information (such as job title) from our HR database (sql server)

I can retrieve data from AD successfully. but when i run the update function, it return the following error:

> General access denied error
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: General access
>   denied error
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add
>   the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and
>   check the boxes for the desired access.

[image]

I had confirmed that the user account (AD) i used already have update right.
In sql management studio, had already build up a ADSI Linked server to the AD.

But still no idea how to solve the problem.

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Following is my code:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
Imports System.Security.Principal

Partial Class Scheduler_AutoUpdate_AD
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Server.ScriptTimeout = 2400
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        ReadAD()
        UpdateAD()

    End Sub


    Sub UpdateAD()       
        Dim de As New DirectoryEntry()
        Dim connection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ADConnectionString2").ToString()

        Dim dssearch As New DirectorySearcher(connection)

        dssearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName=" & txtusername.Text & "))"
        Dim sresult As SearchResult = dssearch.FindOne()
        Dim dsresult As DirectoryEntry = sresult.GetDirectoryEntry()
        'dsresult.Properties("company").Value = "Test1"
        dsresult.Properties("manager").Value = "Test1"
        dsresult.CommitChanges()
        dsresult.Close()

    End Sub

    Sub ReadAD()

        Dim de As New DirectoryEntry()

        Dim connection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ADConnectionString2").ToString()
        Dim dssearch As New DirectorySearcher(connection)
        dssearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" & txtusername.Text & "))"
        Dim sresult As SearchResult = dssearch.FindOne()
        Dim dsresult As DirectoryEntry = sresult.GetDirectoryEntry()

        lblfname.Text = dsresult.Properties("givenName")(0).ToString()
        lbllname.Text = dsresult.Properties("sn")(0).ToString()
        lblemail.Text = dsresult.Properties("mail")(0).ToString()
        lblusername.Text = dsresult.Properties("sAMAccountName")(0).ToString()
        lblipphone.Text = dsresult.Properties("ipPhone")(0).ToString()
        lblusergroup.Text = dsresult.Properties("memberof")(0).ToString()
        lbljobtitle.Text = dsresult.Properties("title")(0).ToString()

    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

you can go with user impersonation: using the credentials of an user allowed to do such actions you can make the ASP.NET application act as the user with higher privileges.
you can save these credentials in the config file (imho not safe because are admin credentials) or require them interactively to the user when accessing the page.

here follow the code i found on the net for the task (i don't remember the source, it is not my work):

```
Public Enum LogonType
    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2
    LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3
    LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 4
    LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 5
    LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7
    LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8
    ' Win2K or higher
    LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9
    ' Win2K or higher
End Enum

Public Enum LogonProvider
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35 = 1
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 = 2
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3
End Enum

Public Enum ImpersonationLevel
    SecurityAnonymous = 0
    SecurityIdentification = 1
    SecurityImpersonation = 2
    SecurityDelegation = 3
End Enum

Class Win32NativeMethods
    <DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function LogonUser(lpszUserName As String, lpszDomain As String, lpszPassword As String, dwLogonType As Integer, dwLogonProvider As Integer, ByRef phToken As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function DuplicateToken(hToken As IntPtr, impersonationLevel As Integer, ByRef hNewToken As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function RevertToSelf() As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Public Shared Function CloseHandle(handle As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function
End Class
''' <summary>
''' Allows code to be executed under the security context of a specified user account.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks> 
'''
''' Implements IDispose, so can be used via a using-directive or method calls;
'''  ...
'''
'''  var imp = new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" );
'''  imp.UndoImpersonation();
'''
'''  ...
'''
'''   var imp = new Impersonator();
'''  imp.Impersonate("myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword");
'''  imp.UndoImpersonation();
'''
'''  ...
'''
'''  using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" ) )
'''  {
'''   ...
'''   1
'''   ...
'''  }
'''
'''  ...
''' </remarks>
Public Class Impersonator
    Implements IDisposable
    Private _wic As WindowsImpersonationContext

''' <summary>
''' Begins impersonation with the given credentials, Logon type and Logon provider.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="userName">Name of the user.</param>
''' <param name="domainName">Name of the domain.</param>
''' <param name="password">The password. <see cref="System.String"/></param>
''' <param name="logonType">Type of the logon.</param>
''' <param name="logonProvider">The logon provider.</param>
Public Sub New(userName As String, domainName As String, password As String, logonType As LogonType, logonProvider As LogonProvider)
    Impersonate(userName, domainName, password, logonType, logonProvider)
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Begins impersonation with the given credentials.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="userName">Name of the user.</param>
''' <param name="domainName">Name of the domain.</param>
''' <param name="password">The password. <see cref="System.String"/></param>
Public Sub New(userName As String, domainName As String, password As String)
    Impersonate(userName, domainName, password, LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
End Sub

' <summary>
' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Impersonator"/> class.
' </summary>
'public Impersonator()
'{ }

''' <summary>
''' Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
''' </summary>
Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    UndoImpersonation()
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Impersonates the specified user account.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="userName">Name of the user.</param>
''' <param name="domainName">Name of the domain.</param>
''' <param name="password">The password. <see cref="System.String"/></param>
Public Sub Impersonate(userName As String, domainName As String, password As String)
    Impersonate(userName, domainName, password, LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Impersonates the specified user account.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="userName">Name of the user.</param>
''' <param name="domainName">Name of the domain.</param>
''' <param name="password">The password. <see cref="System.String"/></param>
''' <param name="logonType">Type of the logon.</param>
''' <param name="logonProvider">The logon provider.</param>
Public Sub Impersonate(userName As String, domainName As String, password As String, logonType As LogonType, logonProvider As LogonProvider)
    UndoImpersonation()

    Dim logonToken As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim logonTokenDuplicate As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Try
        ' revert to the application pool identity, saving the identity of the current requestor
        _wic = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero)

        ' do logon & impersonate
        If Win32NativeMethods.LogonUser(userName, domainName, password, CInt(logonType), CInt(logonProvider), logonToken) <> 0 Then
            If Win32NativeMethods.DuplicateToken(logonToken, CInt(ImpersonationLevel.SecurityImpersonation), logonTokenDuplicate) <> 0 Then
                Dim wi = New WindowsIdentity(logonTokenDuplicate)
                ' discard the returned identity context (which is the context of the application pool)
                wi.Impersonate()
            Else
                Throw New Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
            End If
        Else
            Throw New Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
        End If
    Finally
        If logonToken <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            Win32NativeMethods.CloseHandle(logonToken)
        End If

        If logonTokenDuplicate <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            Win32NativeMethods.CloseHandle(logonTokenDuplicate)
        End If
    End Try
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Stops impersonation.
''' </summary>
Private Sub UndoImpersonation()
    ' restore saved requestor identity
    If _wic IsNot Nothing Then
        _wic.Undo()
    End If
    _wic = Nothing
End Sub
End Class
```

how to use it:

```
    Using imp As Tools.Network.Impersonator = New Network.Impersonator(username, domain, password)
        ' the code that requires privileges goes here
        ' also initialization of objects that requires permission MUST be inside the USING,
        ' objects initialized outside this scope will not be affected
    End Using
```